# XCODE 5 and submission to apple itunes

Tags: xcode4, app-store, xcode5

I have an app that is developed in xcode 4, I Have converted the project to xcode 5 which remained the xcode 4 design, did not adjust it to meet the xcode 5 20 px change and its working fine, yesterday I have received a mail from apple which content is -->

> Make sure your apps work seamlessly with the innovative technologies in iOS 7. Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK. Learn more about building apps for iOS 7.

I entered the apple site and see this -->

> User Interface - Elevate the content of your apps and make your user interface come alive on iOS 7. Adopt the new design to simplify and revitalize your app with clarity, translucency, and depth. UIKit allows you to incorporate realistic motion and transitions with new APIs that enable your user interface to respond to every touch and swipe by following the behaviors and physical constraints you define. Take advantage of powerful new text layout tools and dynamic type that respect the design principles of iOS 7.

should I have to change the design to be like other ios 7 design with the same bar color? should I start changing the UI and make new designs 480*320 and not 460*320 with black bar?

please help me I cant submit the app before 1/2

thanks

Comment: no I still didnt submit it, I wont finish developing before first of february

Comment: As long as you stick to the Human Interface guidelines and Apple review guidelines you will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see why they would have rejected (If they did) because we aren't near the 1st of February yet.

Apple announced on the 17th December 2013 the below (This can be found https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a)

> tarting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7

It's not like weren't expecting this, but your apps should be fine up to the 1st February for any submissions as long as they don't break any of Apples review guidelines and don't go against the Human Interface guidelines. But after the 1st of February any submissions that you do will require your apps to be iOS 7 optimized and work to the new [Human Interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/index.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this mean that we can still support iOS 6?

Comment: Can you please tell me that by `will require your apps to be iOS 7 optimized`, do you mean that we have to use iOS 7 UI standards even if we support iOS version below 7?

Comment: Yes, you will have to support iOS 7 fully and you will have to stick to the new Human Interface Guidelines provided in the answer. You will however be able to still support older iOSs such as 4, 5, 6. In theory nothing has really changed because if you supported iOS 5 you would have to still fully support 7 anyway.

Comment: Ok. Yes, programmatically nothing has changed, but in terms of UI we have to stick to iOS 7 standards.

Comment: There is loads that has changed programmatically, but if you have submitted an app to the app store since iOS 7 has been released you would have had to support iOS 7 anyway. Nothing is changing Apple have just made it official that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a 460x320 view if you make sure it is properly positioned inside both iOS 6 and iOS 7 sized window or view controller bounds (or support iOS 7 only).  For iOS 7, you can put another view or subview behind the status bar if you wish to customize its color.