# Can we use iOS 7 SDK and still support iOS version below 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

A mail from apple states that

```
Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be
built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK.
```

I am confused about what does this mean. Does it mean that apps cannot support iOS version below 7? Can I use Xcode 5 & iOS SDK to build app and *still support iOS 6*?

Comment: Please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109430/xcode-5-and-submission-to-apple-itunes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that you have to make apps using xcode 5 only and also it should support iOS7. Now if you need your app to be compatible with iOS 5 , then you can do this.

Comment: I use Xcode 5. Does it mean that I am using iOS 7 SDK? Is there any way to check SDK version?

Comment: @Geek cannot post comment. Goto Xcode project settings there will be deployment target there. that will be SDK.

Comment: Deployment target and SDK are different. To see SDK installed on your system run this command : `xcodebuild -showsdks`

Comment: No! That's not always true. Check my answer to make sure. But If you didn't do something about it, at the most cases that's true.

Comment: Hey a quick doubt. Are there any chances of app getting rejected if app does not meet `Human Interface Guidelines` of iOS 7? Please note that I submitted app and it got approved which means that it meets guidelines for iOS versions below 7.

Comment: Yes so now you need to check for iOS 7 but also it will be better to be 100 % sure about previous versions too by simply testing app in lower versions too:)

Answer (score 1):

This only means that if you want your app in the App store after Feb 1 (new uploads, guess existing apps are safe for some time), you'll HAVE to build it against the 7 SDK (and XCode 5). That does not mean that you can't support previous iOS versions, you still can (google deployment target, more that that check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424373/1032151)).

For now, if you buid your app against 6 SDK and run it under iOS 7 it will work in compatibility mode, which saves lives sometimes. Since Feb 1 you won't have this opportunity.

**To make sure you're fine after Feb 1:**

1. Use XCode 5.
2. Select your project file and go to Build Settings.
3. Base SDK should be 7 ("Latest iOS" for now).

Answer (score 0):

You must download Xcode 5 (I think that it's run only Maverick Operating System for build iOS7 application) and into general tab on the your project set 6.0 in Deployment Target and run your application.

To be sure to test your application with iOS 6 and iOS 7 devices whereas there are a difference between the two operating system.

[image]